# Unclear borders between inappropriate content and perfect acceptable behavior in chat

Tags: discussion, chat, account-suspension

I am a regular in [Lounge C++](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec) and I got temporarily suspended because of telling a user to get the fuck out because of their choice of compiler ([link may not work](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/32509076/history), [start of the incident here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32509060#32509060)). Now, I do realize I didn't behave in a nice way at all, even though I was just making a joke, but I can't understand why someone making [this "joke"](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32422497#32422497) is OK.

Note I wish no retribution, I just wish to know what is the difference between one case and the other, and please note too that I admit my mistake in

- talking about personal things in the chat, even though there is nothing wrong with it
- making the gtfo joke, that was totally uncalled for

So, what is the difference between jokingly telling someone to gtfo and jokingly telling someone he'd celebrate if they'd die, and why the former is deserving of a suspension while the latter either isn't or the suspension wasn't put in place?

**EDIT**: Now the user who posted the message some time ago [is coming back for more](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32509944#32509944).

Comment: Some chat rooms appear to get in the habit of gradually increasing the limit of acceptable behavior.  Until it blows up, Lounge C++ has been particularly notorious for that.  A suspension is a basic signal to keep that limit in check.

Comment: Were you suspended or just kicked from a flag and put in a time out?

Comment: The link in "because of this" resolves ot "Page not found". If I cannot see it at my reputation level, there's little chance others will be able to see it. When I look at the other "joke", I'm not seeing what is problematic about "So would we, mate." Things to keep in mind: when messages are flagged in chat, they appear in isolation. Also, it is perfectly possible that someone could manage to say something awful at some time and not get flagged for it when someone saying the same thing at some other time gets immediately flagged. Cops don't catch all speeders either.

Comment: @NathanOliver It says my account was suspended, but it is effectively a 30 minute time out.

Comment: @Louis Editing, must be that only I can see it.

Comment: @Louis The problem with the second one is it is a reply to *i remember when i was younger people in my class said they'd celebrate if i died* so the user is saying they would celebrate as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver I see. But unless I've really not been paying attention, what will be shown in flag is the "So would we, mate." without context. One might say "but you can go look". Sure, but it's been my experience that by the time I go look, the flag has been handled one way or another.

Comment: *while the latter either isn't* - I think it's a mistake to assume that anything that doesn't get flagged isn't against the rules. Things get missed.

Comment: @Louis Ah I see where you are coming from.  I also would have invalidated it for that reason.

Comment: *"I can't understand why someone making this "joke" is OK."* It's not, really. But no one flagged it, so they didn't get caught. You were unlucky. Increase your odds of being lucky by not being unnecessarily rude to other users. The whole "Microsoft sucks" thing is so tired and worn out that it isn't even funny anymore.

Comment: @NathanOliver How could it be done otherwise? Most offensive comments are replies to other messages, so they are out of context until you look back, but they may be deserving of a suspension.

Comment: @CodyGray I did flag it, I guess the admin/mod thought it was OK.

Comment: @ChemiCalChems Yes but most of them have offensive material in the reply.  your reply seems like more the exception then the rule.

Comment: @NathanOliver Fair enough. But that way people can avoid being suspended by smartly avoiding to be offensive directly in a reply to another comment but indirectly doing so.

Comment: *I did flag it, I guess the admin/mod thought it was OK.* Ah, it's not clear from your question that someone's saying they want *you* to die. Do you know for sure that the mod declined the flag? (Is that a thing in chat? I almost never use it.)

Comment: @BSMP I doubt a mod was involved. People with enough rep (I don't recall the limit) get to see a notification that contains the actual message that was flagged, out of context, and can validate or invalidate the flag. (I don't recall how many votes are needed either.) There are links to follow if one wants context but as I mentioned to Nathan usually by the time you've taken care to look for context, the flag has been handled.

Comment: @BSMP I have no way of knowing if the flag was declined or not, no.

Comment: Can we burninate the C++ room yet? *runs away*

Comment: @TinyGiant:  That wouldn't be the worst idea.  I'm tired of the meta drama every time something happens in that chat just because someone decided to swear *as a joke*, which is something that's okay when you're in a close environment, but not okay 'round these parts.

Comment: @Makoto I didn't want any drama to take off based on this question. I just wanted to know why I got suspended and someone else didn't, that's it. People saying things are drama is drama itself, it seems.

Comment: I'm upvoting the question because it is a valid thing to ask what the difference is between the 2 behaviors.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For goodness' sake.

**Neither of these things are acceptable.**  Just because you think someone got away with one instance of it doesn't mean that it's okay to keep doing it until one of you eventually get busted.

I'm no denizen of chat at all, but I do know Stack Overflow's policies fairly well.  Given that in the discourse of everyday conversation, if someone were to read either "gtfo" or read "[they'd] celebrate if they'd die" ***sans context***, they'd probably be seriously offended.  It isn't stuff you put up on the main site, and it's not something you should think is okay to put up in chat.

Comment: [**Be Nice**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), it ain't optional.

Comment: Indeed. It's a wonder the Lounge is still permitted to exist, frankly.

Answer (score 21):

The simple explanation is that your comment was flagged, and enough users validated that flag to result in a temporary chat suspension. Likewise, when you flagged an earlier comment by that user, it appears that your flag was invalidated by other users who reviewed it. A comment of "So would we, mate." doesn't appear particularly offensive outside of context, so I can see how an outside reviewer might have dismissed that. Near as I can tell, no moderator reviewed these.

Since then, two of this other user's comments were flagged, those flags were validated by other chat users, and a temporary chat suspension was applied. I've manually extended the suspension of that other user due to the history of misbehavior here.

Inconsistency in handling simply comes down to what was flagged and how other users reviewed those flags. The best way to avoid chat flags is to keep conversations civil.

Answer (score 2):

I refer back to the story of talking to a busy coworker. Would it be acceptable in the workplace? If not, it probably doesn't belong here. Our jokes (freehand circles, 6-8 weeks) are exactly the kind of thing I would expect to find in a workplace. Entertaining, but harmless.

What would happen if you said what you did to a busy coworker? Sometimes nothing, sometimes you get to go meet with HR. This is the latter of the two.

Comment: I work in a mechanics shop, we swear like sailors, your logic does not apply

Comment: I work in a laboratory, we swear like @TinyGiant's workplace